# Inserting rows and dynamic textboxes into a mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, row

Please I need your help with grabbing rows from a table and dynamic text fields, then inserting it inti another table. I'm trying to do is grab some certain state_id from the table below, combine with data from `<input type='text'   name='constituency[]' />` text box displayed on the same page and then insert into table

```
                    +---------+--------------------------+
                    |state_id |  state   |   senatorial  |  
                    |--- -----|----------|---------------|
                    |    1    |  utah    |    A-North    | 
                    |    2    |  utah    |    B-South    |  
                    +---------+----------+---------------+
```

The HTML i'm using to grab information. constituency is a dynamic text field and occur more than once so the need to have it in an array

```
                    <input type='hidden' name="state_id[]"   value="<?php echo $row['state_id'];?>" />
                    <input type='text'   name='constituency[]' />
```

Query I'm using to INSERT into table

```
                    <?php
$constituencys = $_POST['constituency']      ; 
        $state_id = $_POST['state_id']; 


         if(isses($_POST['constituency']))
   {
$constituencys = $_POST['constituency']      ;   
                      foreach($constituencys as          $constituency) {  
     $state_id[$i]= $state_id[$i];
                      $query = mysql_query(" 
         INSERT INTO `constituency` (
                    `constituency_id`,
                    `state_id`,
                    `constituency_name`
                    ) VALUES (
                    NULL,
                    '".$state_id[$i]."',
                    '".$constituency."'
                    "); 
                       }



                    if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
                    echo "Inserted Successfully";
                    }else{
                    echo "No Row Inserted";
                    echo mysql_error() ;
                    echo"<br>Error:".mysql_error();
                   echo"<br>Query:".$query; 
      } } ?>
```

Table I'm inserting to looks like this

```
                    +----------------+-------------+----------------------+
                    |constituency_id |  state_id   |   constituency_name  |  
                    +----------------+-----   -----+----------------------+
```

When I run the code "No Row Inserted"
 is displayed on the screen

Please help me.
I most appreciate it, thank you.

**ERROR SHOWN**

```
    Error: You have an error in your mysql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server for the right syntax to use near " at line 2

Query:
```

Comment: `mysql` has been deprecated, and help is limited. Please use `mysqli` or `PDO`, and you will receive more help.

Comment: You're wide open for SQL injection attacks. Stop working on this code until you've read up and [learned about](http://bobby-tables.com) this problem.

Comment: Turn on error reporting or check your error.log file, I'm sure there's a mysql error somewhere.

Comment: Where you have `echo "No Row Inserted";`, write below it `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: @slash I cant find any error in the Log files.

Comment: @spiritfyre .. After adding mysql_error() , it say's there's an to near line 2 in the query above.

Comment: if(isArray($_POST['constituency'])){                      $constituencys = $_POST['constituency']; 
$state_id = $_POST['state_id']; 
}else{ $constituencys[0] = $_POST['constituency']; 
                      $state_id[0] = $_POST['state_id']; 
                    } can you like this

Comment: Put your query into a variable, and then print it underneath the error, and can you edit your post to include your `echo`ed query, and the resulting error?

Comment: @mmk ... Please what is the logic for that piece of code ?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of `$constituencys[$i]= $constituencys[$i];` and `$state_id[$i]= $state_id[$i];`? You're assigning vars to themselves.

Comment: @user1378680: This code will fail. You need to assign the _text_ of the query to a var, not the query function call itself. I'll post as an answer how the code should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$constituencys = $_POST['constituency']; 
$state_id = $_POST['state_id']; 

$i = 0;
while($i<count($constituencys)){
    $constituencys[$i]= $constituencys[$i];
    $state_id[$i]= $state_id[$i];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `constituency` ( 
        `constituency_id`, `state_id`, `constituency_name`
        ) VALUES (
        NULL,
        '".$state_id[$i]."',
        '".$constituencys[$i]."'
        "; 

    mysql_query($query);          
    $i++;  
}

if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
    echo "Inserted Successfully";
} else {
    echo "No Row Inserted";
    echo "<br><br>Error: " . mysql_error();
    echo "<br><br>Query: " . $query;
} 
?>
```

Try this code first, update your post with results.

**UPDATE**

It looks like you may have 'dirty' input. Make sure you sanitize it for mysql before inserting it, by using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Try the following code.

```
<?php
$constituencys = $_POST['constituency']; 
$state_id = $_POST['state_id']; 

$i = 0;
while($i<count($constituencys)){
    $constit = mysql_real_escape_string($constituencys[$i]);
    $state = mysql_real_escape_string($state_id[$i]);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `constituency` ( 
        `constituency_id`, `state_id`, `constituency_name`
        ) VALUES (
        NULL,
        '$state',
        '$constit')
        "; 

    mysql_query($query);          
    $i++;  
}

if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
    echo "Inserted Successfully";
} else {
    echo "No Row Inserted";
    echo "<br><br>Error: " . mysql_error();
    echo "<br><br>Query: " . $query;
} 
?>
```

**NOTICE**: At the end of your query, you're missing a close parentheses. It has been added in the second example. Ensure it is there before you continue your tests.

```
<?php
$constituencys = $_POST['constituency']; 
$state_id = $_POST['state_id']; 

$query = "INSERT INTO `constituency` (`constituency_id`, `state_id`, `constituency_name`) VALUES";

for($i=0; $i<count($constituencys); $i++){
    $constit = mysql_real_escape_string($constituencys[$i]);
    $state = mysql_real_escape_string($state_id[$i]);
    $query .= "(NULL, '$state', '$constit'), "; 
}
$query = substr(trim($query), 0, -1); //trims then removes trailing comma
mysql_query($query);          

if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
    echo "Inserted Successfully";
} else {
    echo "No Row Inserted";
    echo "<br><br>Error: " . mysql_error();
    echo "<br><br>Query: " . $query;
} 
?>
```

Assuming that your HTML inputs are set up as an array correctly, this should work. It also tidies your code and helps with unwanted lag. Every millisecond counts. :) If this doesn't work, please post returned error and query again.

Comment: Thanks... Now it's inserting, but only one row is being inserted instead of 2 or three as the case may be. When more than one row is meant to be inserted only the first value of `<input type='type' name='constituency[]' />` from the HTML . What can I do ?